# How to have a data-bind if statement for if something is equal to text in a string?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I need to execute code if a certain value is equal to a string (the string is 'stories').

I have:

```
<!-- data-bind if: header.current_collection.url_type == 'stories' -->
    <p>text</p>
<!-- /data-bind -->
```

But it's always false. I put `<p data-bind="text: header.current_collection.url_type"></p>` under it to be sure the value was 'stories' and it displays 'stories' onto the page so I know the value is right.

Why is this being executed as false when it's true. Is there a syntax problem here?

Comment: Can you post the code of your viewmodel?

Comment: `header.current_collection.url_type` is possibly an observable/computed type. Call it as a function if it is. `header.current_collection.url_type() == 'stories'`

Answer (score 1):

Adrian answered this in a comment. You are comparing the observable itself rather than the value. Change it to:

```
if: header.current_collection.url_type() == 'stories'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **strict-equality** '===' instead of '=='?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I agree with the previous answer that you should be using the strict equality operator.  Secondly, you are using incorrect syntax - where you have data-bind should be ko, i.e.:

```
<!-- ko if: header.current_collection.url_type === 'stories' -->
    <p>text</p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

You can find the [knockout if binding docs here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html)

Comment: I've taken over an app and all other if statements use the `data-bind` syntax and not the `ko` syntax. I'm not sure why it is that way but its all through the app and works.

Comment: It's a rails app (fairly old). But I can't figure out why it has that syntax instead of ko

Comment: It's possible this is correct syntax in an older ko version, I haven't been using it long enough to tell you!

Comment: The `ko` prefix is hard-coded into Knockout and has never been different. You must be using a customized version of Knockout or at least a custom binding provider.